# Erro ao tentar buscar um dado da API

Tags: javascript, react, aplicação-web

Estou tentando criar um programa em React que faça conversão de moedas. Nesse caso, de real para dólar utilizando valores atualizados por meio de uma requisição à uma API que contenha esses dados. Acredito que o erro que não está me permitindo rodar o programa é:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'high')*

Este erro já apareceu quando eu usava outra API. A mensagem de erro também apontava o código Javascript dentro da tag `option`. Troquei de API imaginando que esse seria o problema, mas o código entre chaves ainda estava na mensagem de erro.

Meu código:

```
import './index.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {Icon} from "@iconify/react";
import graphics from '../../assets/img/graphics.jpg';
import {SiLinkedin} from "@react-icons/all-files/si/SiLinkedin";
import {GoMarkGithub} from "@react-icons/all-files/go/GoMarkGithub";

const Main = () => {

  const [coins, setCoins] = useState(null);
  const [brl, setBRL] = useState(null);
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState('dolar');

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/last/USD-BRL,EUR-BRL,GBP-BRL');
        setCoins(response.data);
        //console.log(docs);
      
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, [])

  const conversion = () => {
    if (coins) {
      let realFloat = parseFloat(brl);
      switch (choice) {

        case 'dolar':
          let dolarFloat = parseFloat(coins.USD.high);
          let realToDolar = (realFloat / dolarFloat);
          window.alert(`${realFloat} reais equilavem à ${realToDolar.toFixed(2)} dólares.`);
          break;
      
        case 'euro':
          let euroFloat = parseFloat(coins.USD.high);
          let realtoEuro = (realFloat / euroFloat);
          window.alert(`${realFloat} reais equivalem à ${realtoEuro.toFixed(2)} euros.`);
          break;

        case 'libra':
          let libraFloat = parseFloat(coins.GBP.high);
          let realtoLibra = (realFloat / libraFloat);
          window.alert(`${realFloat} reais equivalem à ${realtoLibra.toFixed(2)} libras.`);
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // impede o recarregamento da página ao clicar no botão "converter"
  const envio = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  } 

  return(
    <>
      {coins&&( //renderização condicional => "se coins existir"
        <div className='area'>
          <div className='imgContainer'><img src={graphics} alt='background' className='imgDesign'/></div> 
            <div className='titleInputArea'>
                <h1>Exchange3</h1>
                <input type='number' placeholder='Ex.: R$1 (BRL):' className='field' onChange={(e) => setBRL(e.target.value)}></input>
                  <br></br><h3>Selecione a moeda </h3>
                  <form action="/action_page.php" onSubmit={envio}>
                    <select name="currency" id="currency" className='designCascade' onChange={(e) => setChoice(e.target.value)}>
                      <option value="dolar">Dólar (USD) {coins.USD.high}</option>
                      <option value="euro">Euro (EUR) {coins.EUR.high}</option>
                      <option value="libra">Libra (GBP) {coins.GBP.high}</option>
                    </select><br></br><br></br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Converter" className='submitDesign' onClick={() => conversion()}></input>
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div className='footerBackground'>
              <footer>
                <div className='containerText'>
                  <p>This page was built using ReactJS⚛️ and an API called <a href='https://docs.awesomeapi.com.br/'>Awesome API</a></p>
                </div>
                <div className='containerSocial'>
                  <div className='containerIcons'>
                    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/lucas-souza-franco/'>
                      <SiLinkedin className='icons'></SiLinkedin>
                    </a>
                    <a href='https://linktr.ee/lucassouzafranco'>
                      <Icon icon="simple-icons:linktree" className='icons'/>
                    </a>
                    <a href='https://github.com/lucassouzafranco'>
                      <GoMarkGithub className='icons'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
localhost/:1 
        
       Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exist')
    at chrome-extension://acglggcafiilnibeknihgglelgfafifo/ps.js:2:17
localhost/:1 
        
       Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
index.js:76 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'high')
    at Main (index.js:76:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)

   
       The above error occurred in the <Main> component:

    at Main (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117:76)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

        
       TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'high')
    at Main (index.js:76:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

Comment: Como está vindo `response.data`? Nao conheco a API, mas pode ser que a resposta esteja vindo como um array.

Comment: Eu tentei testar isso fazendo um console.log(coins) e recebi null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz a chamada nesta API e tive o seguinte retorno:

```
 {
  "USDBRL": {
    "code": "USD",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "5.1891",
    "low": "5.1174",
    "varBid": "-0.0489",
    "pctChange": "-0.94",
    "bid": "5.1387",
    "ask": "5.1394",
    "timestamp": "1655828262",
    "create_date": "2022-06-21 13:17:42"
  },
  "EURBRL": {
    "code": "EUR",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Euro/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "5.4914",
    "low": "5.4034",
    "varBid": "-0.0402",
    "pctChange": "-0.74",
    "bid": "5.4098",
    "ask": "5.414",
    "timestamp": "1655828261",
    "create_date": "2022-06-21 13:17:41"
  },
  "GBPBRL": {
    "code": "GBP",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Libra Esterlina/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "6.395",
    "low": "6.2803",
    "varBid": "-0.0554",
    "pctChange": "-0.87",
    "bid": "6.2976",
    "ask": "6.3022",
    "timestamp": "1655828261",
    "create_date": "2022-06-21 13:17:41"
  }
}
```

Vi no seu código que vocês esta tentando acessar uma chave que não existe neste retorno, tente alterar conforme abaixo:

```
coins.USD.high --> coins.USDBRL.high
coins.EUR.high --> coins.EURBRL.high
coins.GBP.high --> coins.GBPBRL.high
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Alem do que o @rharsion comentou, nao sei se foi na hora de inserir a pergunta mas falta um espaco depois de coins {coins&&( //renderização condicional => "se coins existir"...

```
coins && (...
```

De todo modo, para evitar quebrar seu codigo e caso nao queira passar o "coins &&", pode passar "?" antes de chamar o atributo do objeto.

```
ex: coins?.USDBRL?.high
```